# Tag cleanup needed: [multiple-accounts] and [multi-user]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup

Here's a project for us non-Moderators:

The tag [multiple-accounts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-accounts) appears to be covering much of the same ground as [multi-user](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-user).

The tag wiki of the latter currently states:

> Multi-user is a term that defines an operating system, computer program, or a game that allows use by more than one users of the same computer at the same time. Android 4.2 Jelly Bean brought multi-user support to Android tablets.

So, it looks like [multiple-accounts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-accounts) is a candidate to be a synonym for [multi-user](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-user), but it's not currently "clean" enough to force a re-tag.

Here's the project: Go through each of the (currently) 21 questions tagged [multiple-accounts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-accounts) and retag them appropriately. At the very least, anything that is tagged [multiple-accounts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-accounts) *and* [multi-user](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-user) the former is redundant and should be removed. Also, if there are other issues with the question, fix those too.

Once cleaned up to the degree possible we can either let the tag die, set it as a synonym, or, if there are still some questions using it, define an appropriate wiki definition.

Comment: Aren't they distinct? To me it looks like this: [tag:multiple-accounts] => e.g. 2+ Google Play accounts on a single user, or e.g. latitude problems with multiple devices (c.f. [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15012/google-latitude-and-multiple-devices-how-to-prevent-location-jumping)). In contrast: [tag:multi-user] => Android 4.2+ multiuser questions. I already edited some questions though, that contained both tags superflously. Example: What to do about this, it's definitely not multiuser http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14179/multiple-google-accounts-and-the-market

Comment: Edit: Edited every occurrence of double-tags. The questions are all distinct now (either belong to the multi-user or multiple-account kind).

Comment: @ce4: They may be distinct, although "multiple-accounts" doesn't seem very useful. (Certainly no more useful than "accounts".) That's part of the reason I brought it up.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I'm game! Then all [tag:multiple-accounts] should be changed to just [tag:accounts] too.

Comment: Cleanup is done. This question cannot be edited. I only get an error when I try to save: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/new-account-for-gmail-only